# Composition of inverse of measurable functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Given a random variable $X:(\Omega,A)\rightarrow (E,\Sigma)$ and a measurable function $f$, how do I get:
$$
f(X)^{-1}(\Sigma)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(\Sigma))\subset X^{-1}(\Sigma)
$$

Comment: Is measurable function $f$ here a function that has $E$ as domain and as codomain?

Comment: What is the domain and co-domain of $f$?

Comment: That's what I am asking myself, it is from Jacod/Protter p.66 but nothing is said of $f$ other than it is measurable. In the same theorem it is used to show that independence of $X,Y$ is equivalent to independence of $f(X),g(Y)$ for eacht pair $(f,g)$ of measurable functions. Y does not need to take values in the same space as $X$ it is noted.

Comment: It has to be that way @drhab, it is so weird that it is not explicitly stated in the book...

Comment: Yes, it *has to be* that way. That is an *obvious* fact so maybe that made them decide not to mention it. After all you can conclude that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preassume that $f$ is a function $E\to E$.

For every $B\subseteq E$ and every $\omega\in\Omega$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $\omega\in(f\circ X)^{-1}(B)$
- $(f\circ X)(\omega)\in B$
- $f(X(\omega))\in B$
- $X(\omega)\in f^{-1}(B)$
- $\omega\in X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$

And looking at first and last bullet we conclude that for every $B\subseteq E$ we have:$$(f\circ X)^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$$

This leads directly to:$$(f\circ X)^{-1}(\Sigma)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(\Sigma))\tag1$$

where: $$(f\circ X)^{-1}(\Sigma):=\{(f\circ X)^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\Sigma\}$$ and: $$X^{-1}(f^{-1}(\Sigma)):=\{X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))\mid B\in\Sigma\}$$

Now note that measurability of $f$ means exactly that $f^{-1}(\Sigma)\subseteq\Sigma$ so that $(1)$ can be expanded to:$$(f\circ X)^{-1}(\Sigma)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(\Sigma))\subseteq X^{-1}(\Sigma)\tag2$$